# External html file with angular in BootstrapDialog message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-dialog

I want to create `BootstrapDialog` in JavaScript with message contains html file which has angular inside.

HTML:

```
<form id="importTaskForm" name="importTaskForm" class="form-horizontal" action="../tasks/api/task/import" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{msg('task.fileChosen')}}</label>
    <div class="form-inline col-sm-9">
        <file-upload></file-upload>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `<file-upload>` is an angular directive. How can I put this html into `BootstrapDialog` message field?

```
var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
            title: $scope.msg('task.import'),
            message: ???,
            closable: false,
            draggable: false
});
```

Comment: You need to have angular application in order to render angular code.

Comment: @dfsq what do you mean by that? I tried add a html by jquery using $('<div></div>').load('path_to_file), but no angular was loaded

Comment: You need to bootstrap angular app: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: I have angular. I want to load angular directive to dialog message field, but this isn't so easy for me. I'm now trying with $compile, but dialog after action won't be updated or is just freezed.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without a demo.